# How to simulate random returns with numpy

Tags: numpy, random, dataframe, quantitative-finance

What is a quick way to simulate random returns.  I'm aware of `numpy.random`.  However, that doesn't guide me towards how to model asset returns.

I've tried:

```
import numpy as np

r = np.random.rand(100)
```

But this doesn't feel accurate.  How are others dealing doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest one of two approaches:

---

**`One:`**
 Assume returns are normally distributed with mean equal to 0.1% and stadard deviation about 1%.  This looks like:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(314)
r = np.random.randn(100) / 100 + 0.001
```

`seed(314)` sets the random number generator at a specific point so that if we both use the same seed, we should see the same results.

`randn` pulls from the normal distribution.

I'd also recommend using `pandas`.  It's a library that implements a `DataFrame` object similar to `R`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(r)
```

You can then plot the cumulative returns like this:

```
df.add(1).cumprod().plot()
```

[image]

---

**`Two:`**
The second way is to assume returns are log normally distributed.  That means the log(r) is normal.  In this scenario, we pull normally distributed random numbers and then use those values as the exponent of *`e`*.  It looks like this:

```
r = np.exp(np.random.randn(100) / 100 + 0.001) - 1
```

If you plot it, it looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(r).add(1).cumprod().plot()
```

[image]

Comment: comprehensive answer. Lots of work done on this for traded option valuation so maybe worth searching for stuff people have done on that. If you assume that the stock could go up or down each time period in a binary way depending on its volatility but trends in line with risk free return rate then as the time period reduces this binomial distribution trends towards log normal

Comment: Any special reason to use `r = np.random.randn(100) / 100 + 0.001` instead of `r = np.random.normal(0.001, 0.01, size=100)`? I usually prefer the latter since it is extremely clear what is the mean and what is the stddev.